# Testing Jersey REST resource (invalid return response)

Tags: java, rest, jersey, jersey-2.0, dropwizard

I'm trying to test a specific jersey resource but the jersey client is returning a response `InboundJaxrsResponse` while I'm expecting a `OutboundJaxrsResponse`. I don't understand this behavior.

I did investigate with the debugger and the resource is returning a `OutboundJaxrsResponse` as expected, which means that the jersey client is making a wrapping/conversion somewhere, but i don't understand why.

If I'm not doing it right can you tell me a good way of comparing the Response.

I'm using dropwizard.

```
 @Test
public void itShouldRetrieveListOfComputations() {

    List<Computation> computations = new ArrayList<Computation>();
    computations.add(new Computation("name1", "description1", "expression1"));
    computations.add(new Computation("name2", "description2", "expression2"));
    when(computationDAO.findAll()).thenReturn(computations);

    Response expected = Response.ok(computations).build();
    assertThat(resource.client().target("/computations").request().get()).isEqualTo(expected);

    verify(computationDAO).findAll();
}
```

The resource under test

```
 @GET
@UnitOfWork
@Timed
public Response list() {

    List<Computation> computations = computationDAO.findAll();

    Response response = Response.ok(computations).build();
    return response;
}
```

The consequences

```
org.junit.ComparisonFailure: 
Expected :OutboundJaxrsResponse{status=200, reason=OK, hasEntity=true, closed=false, buffered=false} 
Actual   :InboundJaxrsResponse{context=ClientResponse{method=GET, uri=/computations, status=200, reason=OK}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Response.ok(computations).build();` creates an outgoing response that Jersey uses to send to a client. You can't really use that to compare to an in-coming Response from a client call. They are two different implementations of an abstract class.

This is how I generally validate responses:

```
Response response = resource.client().target("/computations").request().get(Response.class);

assertThat( response.getStatusInfo.getFamily() ).isEqualTo( Response.Status.Family.Success );
assertThat( response.getMediaType() ).isEqualTo( MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE );
assertThat( response.readEntity(new GenericType<List<Computation>>() {}) ).isEqualTo( computations );
```